# How to convert from GDSII to Gerber or ODB++ for PCB printing?

Tags: cad, odb

I've generated a very simple GDS file describing a PCB file (layer 0: board cutout, 1: topside metallization, 2: vias) using gdspy. I'm trying to get this PCB printed at [Sunstone](https://www.sunstone.com/); however, they require gerber or ODB++ files. I'm new to PCB printing, and I'm wondering **what my options are to convert from the .gds file to a Gerber or ODB++ file**.

I have found some paid softwares that claim to accomplish this conversion, but which I would rather not use, for example:
https://www.artwork.com/gerber/oasis2gbr/index.htm

I do, however, have access to softwares like KLayout and Eagle.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert gds to gerber by using Layout Editor free version. But total size is limited in free version.